# Resize a div by id onclick jquery

Tags: jquery, html, video, css

I have a website that I am trying to build, I want to use html5 to play any video files I have on the site. I also want to be able to click on the div that holds the video file and on click have the video file transition to fill as much of the screen as possible.

I have looked into jquery and css3 and a lot of what I have found is to make text bigger and stuff like that.

I thought I could do something along the lines of getElementById("#divid").style.height:

and then use somesort of transition to fill in the gap between the two sizes.

here is the site I wanted to implement this in:

http://www.uvm.edu/~areid/stevesite/steveaudio.html

each of the larger rectangles would have a video file within and when clicked would grow to fill the entire container.

**edit**: here is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript"       src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#col1A').bind('click', function() {
       $(this).animate({width: "900px", height: "800px"}, 400);
     });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="col1A" ></div>
</body>


#col1A{
   border: solid;
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: #f9b5b5;
   height: 100px;
   width: 50px;
   border-radius: 20px;
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's quick example of how to do this with CSS3 and a little jQuery : http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gdNue/10/

Comment: this looks very promising
im going to bed now but will give this a shot tomorrow thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) jquery function... The final parameter is the milliseconds.

```
 $("#id_div_to_resize").animate({widht: "900px", height: "800px"}, 400);
```

This will transition from the old size to the new (900 x 800);

If you want to attach that behavior to a click...

```
$("#id_div_to_resize").bind('click', function() {

         $(this).animate({widht: "900px", height: "800px"}, 400);

 });
```

Comment: this seems very logical but for some reason I still cannot get it to animate - i noticed that you misspelled width so that was not the issue. any idea what might be going on - im going to update my original post with my code

Comment: a side note - i am using chrome